# Android Firebase DataSnapshot Cast to Class

Tags: android, class, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, snapshot

I have a firebase database.
When I get value from the snapshot, I have HashMap in below:

[image: HashMap from the snap]

and I have a Snap class like below. How can I cast the DataSnapshot to List of the class such as 
`List<Snap> snapList = (HashMap<String,Object>) dataSnapshot.child(USER_PHONE).child("friends").getValue();`

```
public class Snap {

    String key;
    String value;

    public  Snap(){

    }
    public Snap(String key, String value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way in Java in which you can cast a `HashMap<String,Object>` to a `List<Snap>`. What can you do instead, is to query your database and get all the `Snap` objects and then add them to a `List<Snap>`.

```
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Snap snap = ds.getValue(Snap.class);
            snapList.add(snap);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
        Log.d("TAG", error.getMessage()); //Never ignore potential errors!
    }
};
yourRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```